# Python Regex in Zapier issue

Tags: python, regex, zapier

I am trying to take a field from salesforce that has line breaks and pull out the words and punctuation with a python step in zapier. Here is my code but it returns and empty string. If there is a better/easier way let me know, I am super new to any code and Frankensteined this together from googling.

```
import re

string = input_data['ac']

regex = r"^[a-z,A-Z].*[?.!]$"

cleaned = re.findall(regex, string)

return [{'cleaned': cleaned}]
```

Here are 2 pictures of, original comment and the current result, I have it working but would like to keep the punctuation by updating code.

[Original Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5C0g.png)

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE0Tu.png)

[JSON parser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUAHe.png)

Comment: Your regex has `^` and `$` anchors so it is either going to match the entire input or nothing. So doing a `findall` makes no sense since there cannot possibly be multiple occurrences with these anchors unless you were using the `re.MULITLINE` flag (perhaps you should remove these anchors). What does the actual input look like?

Comment: Usually the input is a few short sentences with a return.
"This job is for the bridge
it has 30 tons per section
sections will be shipped separately"

Comment: I means show us *all* of  the actual text and what the expected output `cleaned` would be.

Comment: Its hard to tell in that comment but each sentence or phrase is on a new line

Comment: Just edit your question with the entire input and expected list of strings of expected output.

Comment: Ok updated but basically take a few sentences on different lines and pull out strings with punctuation. The reason I need to do this is for another step where I use json to post a webhook and the new line or carriage return breaks the json.

Answer (score 0):

The following just finds sentences by looking for a letter and then scanning until it finds one of the sentence-terminating characters.

```
import re

s = input_data['ac'] 

# remove multiple, consecutive carriage returns and/or newlines
s = re.sub(r'[\r\n]+', '', s)

regex = r"""(?x)   # verbose flag
[A-Za-z]    # a letter
[^?.!]*     # one or more non-sentence-ending characters or .*? (non-greedy)
[?.!]       # a sentence-ending character
"""

cleaned = re.findall(regex, s)
result = [{'cleaned': cleaned}] 
#return result # only legal in a function
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ToX26r/1/)

Comment: This works except the \n breaks the json on the the next step. It would be ideal if it was just one long string with punctuation if possible.

Comment: I don't understand your JSON issue. I updated the answer to create the list with the single dictionary and to then convert it into a JSON string and print the result. Newline characters present no problem for JSON. But if you do not like the newline characters. Then take your input and replace your newline characters with perhaps a single space: `s = s.replace('\n', ' ')` or `s = re.sub(r'\n+', ' ', s)` to replace multiple newlines with a single space.

Comment: Do you not want separate sentences?

Comment: adding the  s = s.replace('\n', ' ') was closer but it added a comma at the end so it had a period and then comma at end ., and adding that also created the JSON parser error which I added to the original post.

Comment: 1. You never, as asked, showed what the complete actual input was. 2. There is *per se* nothing illegal about newlines and commas in string literals as far as parsing JSON input. But clearly there is extra rules being enforced here generating your JSON_PARSER_ERROR. Without knowing what these rules are precisely and where in the strings these characters are, you cannot expect miracles. Go back and read your question as posted. Do you believe you completely expressed your problem? 3. And let's be precise: ` s = s.replace('\n', ' ')` didn't *add* anything to the end of anything (more ...)

Comment: But, of course, I have no idea what the "end" is since I have no idea what your complete input text even looks like. STILL.

Comment: Looks like a comma was added because it broke it into two strings.
You keep saying you have no idea what the complete input text is, I don't know what you want. The pic in the post is the input text I get. Since I am new on this board if you could give me an example of the "Original Comment" picture from above in a way that helps I will keep that in mind for future posts.

Comment: Nothing I did added a comma. And how is your "answer" different than mine?

Comment: s = s.replace('\r\n', ' ') is the only difference.

Comment: As far as an 'answer' goes what is the protocol, leave the one that didnt work and and just add to these comments what did or post as one piece? Again not sure how I am supposed to do it or why your getting mad.

Comment: My experience is that `\n` os Windows systems will match carriage return-linefeed combinations and it is not necessary to specify `\r\n`, whereas your regex will fail on unix systems.

Comment: There, answer deleted and Ill add it under here so people have to dig for it.

import re



s = input_data['ac']


s = s.replace('\r\n', ' ')

regex = r"""(?x)  # verbose flag

[A-Za-z]  # a letter

[^?.!]*   # one or more non-sentence-ending characters or .*? (non-greedy)

[?.!]    # a sentence-ending character

"""



cleaned = re.findall(regex, s)

return [{'cleaned': cleaned}]

Comment: I am not mad. Just frustrated in that I have been trying to help and you have been supplying NONE of the information that I have been asking for such as what the input is and what the output rules are, saying my answer doesn't work without really explaining what your requirements are, and then posting an answer that is a duplicate of mine. In about a minute I will be deleting my answer and you can then start over with somebody else or just plagiarize my answer.